# Regular expression of a string that contains one or more a's

Tags: javascript, regular-language

I just read somewhere that the regular expression of a string that contains one or more a's is: `(b*ab*)*.`
I don't think this is correct,it doesn't create the baab string or baaaaab string for example.
Is that correct?

Comment: The regex for a string containing one or more a's is `.*a.*`.  Can you show us sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

That's not right. Something like this should work: /.*a.*/gi

The "." captures any character, and "*" captures any number (0 or more) of the character before it. So, in English, that regular expression says something like "capture any String that contains any number of characters, followed by an A, followed by any number of characters." Check out https://regexr.com/ for help building regular expressions. It has a great reference on the left and a live editor.

Comment: so this is a valid regular expression: (a+b)*a(a+b)* ?

Comment: It's technically valid, but that wouldn't be useful for finding a string that contains one or more A's